# Call Twitter Endpoint API to follow another user Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, endpoint

I'm using Twitter end point API to follow another user. The API is:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json?follow=&screen_name=&user_id=

with Authorization header passed as:

```
@Headers("Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=DC0sePOBbQ8bYdC8Smg,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,oauth_timestamp=1502774524,oauth_nonce=175308858,oauth_version=1.0,oauth_token=712057165-iQB4b4Q0hsNmHsAxiW4X5UF5xVB6JmKOPhxnW,oauth_signature=X0GExH5DBVgVv49jkO3LwfX8%3D")
@POST()
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<ResponseBody> followUser(@Url String url, @Field("follow") boolean follow, @Field("screen_name") String screenName, @Field("user_id") String userId);
```

in Retrofit API call from Android. This works fine. But the Auth header has to be generated dynamically for every logged in user. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Header annotation in parameter list. Please check the official [documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Header.html).

> Replaces the header with the value of its target.

```
 @GET("/")  
 Call<ResponseBody> foo(@Header("Accept-Language") String lang);
```

> Header parameters may be null which will omit them from the request.
>   Passing a List or array will result in a header for each non-null
>   item.
>
> Note: Headers do not overwrite each other. All headers with the same
>   name will be included in the request.

Comment: Yes, but I need to know how to get value for these parameters, twiter auth header specific values: